# .htaccess blocks access to subfolders

Tags: apache, .htaccess, subdirectory

Goal: I want to prevent directory traversal by using .htaccess  (Even though it's not very good practice).

Situation: I have this line in .htaccess: `Options All -Indexes`

And sure enough, entering `localhost/rootfolder/page.php` is allowed, but entering `localhost/rootfolder/` returns a `403 Forbidden` page (expected).

Problem: However, I suspect that because of the `Options All -Indexes` in the .htaccess, I am not able to even draw files from subfolders.

For example, I have an image with file path `rootfolder/subfolder/image.png` that is displayed using `<img src=./subfolder/image.png>`. The image that appeared returns a "broken image".

Right clicking > View image opens the image using the file path appended to the localhost, i.e. `localhost/rootfolder/subfolder/image.png`, returns a `403 Forbidden` page as well.

Question: How do I use .htaccess to block access to directory viewing, but still allow the individual files in subfolders be accessed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the following line in htaccess :

```
RedirectMatch 403 ^/folder/?$
```

This will forbid a request for /folder , but you can access your files and subfolders.

Comment: Please check your error log for info about the error.

Comment: The log says that it has no problems fetching the css file. It returns the 500 error when it is fetching the php file: "GET /home.css HTTP/1.1" 304 -, "GET /home.php HTTP/1.1" 500 1076

Comment: Then the problem is in your php setup not in htaccess.